# Convert Date timestamp to Date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert a timestamp to a regular date format? My API gives date output as `/Date(1680652800000)/`, I need to convert it to readable date.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You can try with regex .

Comment: maybe slice it to remove some chars `"/Date(1680652800000)/"[6:-2]` to get string `"1680652800000"`, next use `int()` to convert to integer, and later use `datetime` to convert it to object `datetime` which has `.strftime()` to format readable date

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

timestamp_str = "/Date(1680652800000)/"
timestamp = int(re.search(r'\d+', timestamp_str).group())
timestamp_seconds = timestamp / 1000
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_seconds)
print(date)
```

Output

```
2023-04-05 06:00:00
```

Comment: perfect, works like charm. Thank you

Comment: @BlockChainLearner most welcome

Answer (score 1):

Given a well-known string format as shown in the question then you can just slice it.

You would also need to know the Epoch upon which the timestamp is based. It will not necessarily be that same as Python's default.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

ds = "/Date(1680652800000)/"

ms = int(ds[6:-2])

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(ms // 1_000, timezone.utc))
```

**Output:**

```
2023-04-05 00:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
timestamp = int(re.search(r'[\d]+', "/Date(1680652800000)/").group(0))
date = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ms').date()
print(date)
```

Output is:

```
2023-04-05
```

Comment: This method fails to implement "pandas as pd" and uses regex to search for the timestamp. The size of the timestamp will be known ahead of time, it would be better to index and use the datetime python module instead.